# SQL multiple where and fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have data organized in 2 tables as such:

**Meetings**
meet_id
meet_category

**Orders**
order_id
meet_id
order_date

I need to write a single query that returns the total number of meetings, the number of meetings with a category of "long" and the number of meetings with a category of "short". 
Count only the meetings that have at least one order_date after March 1, 2011.

The output should be in 3 fields and 1 row

So far I what I have is:

```
SELECT COUNT(m.meet_id),
COUNT(SELECT m.meet_id WHERE m.meet_category = 'long'),
COUNT(SELECT m.meet_id WHERE m.meet_category = 'short')
FROM Meetings m
INNER JOIN Orders o
ON m.meet_id = o.meet_id 
WHERE o.order_date >= '2011-03-01';
```

That is what first comes to mind, but this query doesn't work and I am not even sure if my approach is the correct one. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(m.meet_id),
SUM(CASE WHEN m.meet_category = 'long' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN m.meet_category = 'short' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Meetings m where  meet_id in 
    (select meet_id
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE o.order_date >= '2011-03-01');
```

Comment: Pay attention, this query works only on MySql, because meet_category not include in group by clause

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select count(1) as total_count,innerqry.*

(
select count(m.meet_id), meet_catagory
Meetings m
INNER JOIN Orders o
ON m.meet_id = o.meet_id 
and m.meet_id in 
(select meet_id from orders where order_date>= '2011-03-01')

group by meet_category
) innerqry
```

if you want only one row and you have few known meeting types  try this

```
SELECT COUNT(m.meet_id),
SUM(CASE WHEN m.meet_category = 'long' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN m.meet_category = 'short' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Meetings m
INNER JOIN Orders o
ON m.meet_id = o.meet_id 
WHERE  m.meet_id in 
(select meet_id from orders where order_date>'2011-03-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(m.meet_id),
(select count(*) from meetings m2 join orders o2 on o2.meet_id = m2.meet_id where m2.meet_category = 'long' and o2.order_date >= '2011-03-01'),
(select count(*) from meetings m2 join orders o2 on o2.meet_id = m2.meet_id where m2.meet_category = 'short' and o2.order_date >= '2011-03-01')
FROM mettings m
INNER JOIN Orders o
ON m.meet_id = o.meet_id
WHERE o.order_date >= '2011-03-01';
```

You must implement two indipendent subqueries because you want a total number in your main query without grouped by meet_id, so if you try to link subquery with field in main query you have an error about grouped by fields.